# New Users feeling unwelcomed

Tags: discussion

The recent blog post https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ says that minority users feel unwelcome.

Would hiding new users identity help with that?  Show everyone with a rep under a certain limit as the same: same avatar, same username.  Links to their profile would of course work, but their questions and answers would be semi-anonymous.

Comment: No, because they are not unwelcome. They *feel* unwelcome. But that is a different thing.

Comment: @Raedwald: Maybe they would feel less unwelcome if it was made more explicit that any downvote or negative coment was directed at their post, because nobody knows it's them.

Comment: If a new user do a small effort to read the help section, take the tour of the website then start answering/asking following rules he will be more than welcome

Comment: But if a user create an account and after 1min he hit the "ask a question" and say "help I have a problem !" then he may feel unwelcome simply because he's not respecting the rules and not doing any effort. I don't think there is any relation with reputation or identity

Comment: Anonymity won't affect the quality of the question they post and the post will still be voted on accordingly. It's upto them what they perceive as "unwelcome".

Comment: The anonymity would give **us** more ammo to explain that they aren't targeted. It won't change their feeling of targetting, though.

Comment: @jmoreno: the vast majority of comments are directed towards the *content of the post*, yet a subset of users still see that as being targeted at them personally. How would anonymity help there?

Comment: [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366762/2751851) is spot on. I would add that *enforced* anonymity is a steep price to pay.

Answer (score 13):

I'd argue that it's less of an identity perception and more of a culture perception.  Users feel unwelcomed because the culture oppresses them in ways more nuanced than just their reputation.

Hiding a user's identity wouldn't even come close to addressing any real problems, given that regardless of the reputation one has, one *still* has experiences with questions or answers that may put one off from the site.

Answer (score -17):

Stack Overflow has a hostility problem and it's not just directed at new users. I rarely ask questions because the answers in my area of inquiry rarely get answered, the replies are low quality and some are so hostile, I deleted the questions.

Stack Overflow has a problem with informing new users how it works or a problem conveying how it works. When I answer questions and the user reputation is 1, there's usually several duplicate answers already available. For some reason new users don't understand that. I do my best to give a good answer, that is tested, usually with references and examples, but there's no reward for dealing with new users. The standard rote reply is that they still have the same problem or no reply at all. They refuse to post their code. There's rarely an acknowledgement of the answer. New users are usually a hassle and they don't add to the knowledge base and that's why I think there's a hostility towards them.

As an example, my highest rated answer on Stack Overflow is 2. Most of my answers have a reputation of 0. On other stack exchange sites, my answers get far more upvotes. Overall, my answers are strong enough that my reputation is currently in the top 8% for this year, so I feel I am contributing. I should mention that I am a fairly a new user.

**Edit** I am not on Stack Overflow looking for praise for my answers. I just mentioned some things that are frustrating, like the lack of respect for people asking questions. The lack of followup when people answer a question, but no reply if it worked or didn't work. I'm here to improve my skills and share my knowledge, not pick up gold stars. I see that new users don't follow up the most, which is why I mentioned my low-rated answers.

Comment: Care to explain how the voting, which is a quality control mechanism, means it's hostile? Hostile means you get insulted, berated, attacked. I see none of that in what you explain.... You're basically saying "users don't agree my answers are good, I feel attacked by this".....

Comment: Also... I took a second to check some of your answers. I looked at 2 answers currently scored at 2. One of the posts has 28 views, the other 35 views. Getting a bit under 10% of visitors to upvote your answers is lacking respect towards you? I feel like the view you have of the site isn't aligned with how it is...

Comment: @Patrice Voting down an answer without a reply to why. Posting a an answer or reply that berates the user for not posting all of their code when the code wasn't the question or needed for the answer. Insulting the user in a reply and never even attempting to answer the question.

Comment: @Patrice, I posted how I feel as a new user and why I think there's a hostility to new users. I'm now sitting at a -3 for my effort. I think it's safe to say Stack Overflow has a hostility problem. As for my answers, there's rarely an acknowledgment that the answer fixed the issue that I get from more experienced users which is frustrating for people who are looking to help.

Comment: 'Voting down an answer without a reply to why' - you don't want to know.  Why? Someone might tell you.  There may then be a street-fight, and both you and the answerer could get suspended.

Comment: @MartinJames In my case I want to know. Downvoting without a reply does not fix an issue. If someone is on SO itching for a street fight, they're posting on the wrong web site.

Comment: 'Stack Overflow has a huge problem with informing new users how it works.' - there is a lot of information offered to new users, they acknowledge that they have read it. and they can always read it again via the help. If new users don't actually read what is freely given and available then....

Comment: @gwally not me - I'm trying to help you avoid one.  I have not looked at, nor voted on in any way, your question, so if a fight breaks out, I'm on the sidelines:)

Comment: @MartinJames I edited my reply because it was not directed at you. In the past I have deleted questions because I was not looking for a fight, I was looking for a solution to a problem.

Comment: @gwally Getting upvotes just takes time. There are so many posts on SO that posts probably aren't seen by as many users as on smaller sites or on tags with less traffic. Your posts and comments look good, so you shouldn't worry.

Comment: There is a point to be made that most of the users who say they want to know, when they are informed of reasons for downvotes, fight, argue and insult the person who explained.it is extremely disheartening to explain yourself, get abused for it, and then see everywhere 'but please explain yourself!'. Being welcoming goes both ways.... Oh. And you being at -3 here is because 3 users **disagree** with your stance. You posted your perception/opinion. Users disagree. In which world is disagreement hostile?

Comment: @ModusTollens Thank you. If I want upvotes, I can go to stack exchange sites and get them quickly, but that's not my goal. I post on SO to look at problems, solve them, which improves my skills in coding. I post answers to help the user and help others looking for a solution. Without trying to be a rockstar, my reputation is in the top 8% for the year, so I know I am going the right direction. Many of my answers are for a limited audience, so I don't expect many upvotes which is good because I don't get them.

Comment: @gwally Oh, I got the impression that you don't feel welcome at SO because your posts don't get enough upvotes. What else is the reason then? You mentioned some points at the beginning, but those are cases you can handle: downvote bad answers, flag hostile ones (don't delete them).

Comment: I just realized there is one piece I haven't touched on yet: you are right, you shouldn't get hostile answers. Now, not being able to see them I can't say I would find them hostile, but that's not the point. Everyone on SO deserves respect. If you didn't get it, it is indeed a shame.

Comment: @ModusTollens When answers don't have a followup, it's frustrating because I see answers as what my solution would be to an issue. With followup, like it worked/didn't work, I can improve my answers, improve my skills, solve other user problems. I don't need an attaboy. I'm just using my answers to improve my skills. It's working. I just wanted to mention an issue and since it's usually new users, a reason there's hostility towards them.

Comment: @gwally Now I get you and I agree. It can be very frustrating to not get any feedback. I deal with it by not expecting it any more, so it is a nice surprise when it happens :)

Comment: In my experience I get much more follow up when I answer questions posted by experienced users, ones who know the importance of this, and much less when answering questions posted by newbies. I figure it is one of the risks of answering newbie questions, and I accept it.

Comment: `I'm just using my answers to improve my skills. It's working.` This! :) . . . In my experience, a welcoming feedback on my answers from the question asker is a rarity.